# replace numbers in class names by javascript

Tags: html, regex

Why doesn't my script work?

I want to replace numbers in this code:

```
<!--m-->
<li class="g videobox" style="position:relative">
<div class="s">
<table class="ts" style="width:auto">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top:5px;padding-right:8px" valign="top" width="1%">
<div class="th" style="background-color:#000;height:68px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:120px">
<a id="v0" style="text-decoration:none" href="/url?url=http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xt80kj_2nd-september-2012-southampton-vs-manchester-united-2-3-hd_sport&amp;rct=j&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=P2hEUIfkKYKk0QXppoHgCA&amp;ved=0CDwQuAIwAA&amp;q=manchester&amp;usg=AFQjCNGmLl3hg6CUcX5MsuU-njXolHOOlQ">
<div style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="" id="vidthumb1" class="th vidthumb1" style="display:inline-block;height:67px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;border:0;width:120px" align="middle" border="0" height="67" width="120">
</div>
<span class="vdur" style="right:0;background-color:#000;bottom:0;color:#000;filter:alpha(opacity=70);font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;opacity:0.7;-khtml-opacity:0.7;-moz-opacity:0.7;padding:1px 3px;position:absolute;text-align:right;text-decoration:none">►&nbsp;4:01</span>
<span class="vdur" style="right:0;bottom:0;color:#fff;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;padding:1px 3px;position:absolute;text-align:right;text-decoration:none">►&nbsp;4:01</span>
</a>
</div>
</td>
<td style="padding-top:1px" valign="top">
<h3 class="r inl">
<a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xt80kj_2nd-september-2012-southampton-vs-manchester-united-2-3-hd_sport" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','0','','1','AFQjCNFZjowZj8K920o31HeauBkHuwmpzA','6LR8Li4Qt3qhz4xWQE49yQ','0CDsQtwIwAA',null,event)" title="2nd September 2012 Southampton vs Manchester United 2-3 [HD] - Video Dailymotion">2nd September 2012 Southampton vs <em>Manchester</em> <b>...</b>
</a>
</h3>
<div> <cite class="kv">dailymotion.com</cite>
<span class="st">
<span class="f">
<span style="background:#aaa;border:#999 1px solid;border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;color:#fff;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;margin-right:5px;padding:0 3px;text-transform:uppercase">New</span>
<span class="nobr">14 hours ago</span> - <span class="nobr">4 min</span>
</span>
<br>2nd September 2012 Southampton vs <em>Manchester</em> United 2-3 [HD]<br>
</span>
</div> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--n-->
<!--m-->
</li>
<li class="g videobox" style="position:relative">
<div class="s">
<table class="ts" style="width:auto">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top:5px;padding-right:8px" valign="top" width="1%">
<div class="th" style="background-color:#000;height:68px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:120px">
<a id="v0" style="text-decoration:none" href="/url?url=http://www.footytube.com/video/southampton-manchester-united-sep02-127801&amp;rct=j&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=P2hEUIfkKYKk0QXppoHgCA&amp;ved=0CD8QuAIwAQ&amp;q=manchester&amp;usg=AFQjCNGWDlz10zch_sUaWuQ63AO88LPtzA">
<div style="position:relative;top:-1px;left:0px">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5Ojf/2wBDAQoKCg0MDRoPDxo3JR8lNzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzf/wAARCABGAHgDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAGwAAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUDBAYBAgf/xAA1EAACAQMDAgQDBgYDAQAAAAABAgMABBEFEiETMQZBUWEicYEUMjORobEHFRYjQsFSU9Hw/8QAGQEAAgMBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMAAQQF/8QAIxEAAgICAgICAwEAAAAAAAAAAAECEQMhEjETQSJhBCMyUf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A+c3IWWCJQxXIQZYeuKd6HqMmmkxxuXiD4whxvfHmPQDH0qobGW4trV4+ngxruDk5J/1Vn+WTQxiW3IeR1V4yF8/P5+VL6OjJxn6PM1zLFenUGuVLg7mdO6/8uP2+dbTRk1BLaIS6jbXMDSN1muwjOwx/bMZUgj0PvWQ13T7zS0t4bk280d4wmE8RbCuByhB7dwfzpro/hy7R1LJBD8IuFfO4KqkZX2JGabCbXaETgpwu+jQS+INuTLYampCMVLLtJC8DAI7kdquWlqL+8tJZZru0LIrLCXUHjB2nae/HPzNK/wCJAKtpjh9mbeRSSe+cVQ8JB5PEtoxnkmi6a7FZvuAf/CinJOtGaDdtom1DxnZWF1Pbvb3s8kVw0Z+NMkoSM+4NZ/WdTt9Ta7ubiHom52MYoxjZx8P6rVTXWjhv9WmY7pBqUoxt+7yf/TVG8t7g2No8i70KALKmSSAcjPp5/nQpOROketTeO1ltHhyqhQxAONwIP6etR2t51NT3wb41d/hjX34qvdXVxfRW9tI29Ub4SR8Q4wAPbkV2NP5TqSrcpvZQQyA8hscAe9U4jFK2mTTpHHLNGOpuAYkg9wewI8qs6MiOUWZytupydowwbHHxfQVXns7lFkupXjLSrucMM5z5fOptIt9RvbFrWxtbidnOcJHx3PG7t6VSiw/Jdpsv+IbpJLcEbXjRlCjzzk5/TFKEmjnvlkXbF32bhlQRjGa0jeGrp9LuIr2CSznithOobt1Ry3bgqR5eWBWSURiRJY2PTKqWH71dUB7VdDHT36N1fCXCtIg2My8AgnOD+VFeUaSLCuAykfCoOe/NFD8g/wBb7ZoXto44oIpFUSLEjMVYjI2g/wC68hrqWBEthtRCyq27kAgZGPSlCXt3dSM2JGhWNELFccYArn821K0uJLaGNljQ5+JMn0paa52aJNeNRo0d5byan4et3IDizug74PI4Kn6dqbaaLidGIn6IKk9NV3KceQJrAi/u4JY47eWcK4AkjViBkk7hjsas2esX1rqPQtZZ1jluAHXGdvI9uPPtTUxEo6o2/wDEmN5oNOQkFBAxYbsHORjBpJ4Amf8AqhF4XvkY880w/iq0QOjCZZFjZXJ2DORjtSz+HUN1Drtm1xE6qwYh2GB5fWo3dFYq8cvsUalZi58W3cM0bG3l1KQPzjjcc1uS2kW6XmlQQYglMe2ADJGADw3oCMkUhuns7fxFqM18zLALmQF2U4ByR6VTbxLBo9+XtrVbyGSIFJmYqSD5jjt2ojOn/pQt1sk1i4gvFwUUlZAABnIYcfTH0rV6Stna+Ipr2BBLcmBSd4DKnALfInisRJb3F9umtLaR3wWbA759zTiLVP6c1V7yeCWeO4ZI5I923gRj7pPnkVS0x8oxUVTPfioWF8YF0bZDHGxSfCEHjlTz9R69q0fh3UriCyhtI7ZoUDHDKQQy+eR86x6WFw9zPcp12tLppZDuGOkS2V47ng+/amGm+MLawSC3u7KaKSFsNLH8S4A81POflRRewJ1xGvinXpY2s9Pu4nZpo96Pu27csVPHmCOKzllYW91rUyMitBAp3qPoAD79z9KY+JPEOneIJbZ7USN0EZS7x7CTnIxnnA55NKZrma1gklVtu4HJHG49uTUyYnNWmF+PnhifyVjHWtMtkgW5soOnLCQNpbhweMUVzTdTbVbVoLxWbpptBVdxA8s49/Ois8OUFUtmrM8WVqUVRLpGlxyRR3LBSuwZjx3+Hz/KvJ8O7b9mW5DGVACFzwwx+mKk0m+6GmxRG3ckxj4gw9CP91ONQ3IRLbHef84zj0x+360tNJ7JLyMhXRFR5cyBVIUtJIPu8f7Pl71yHS2EcUv2gK5kBCoOcBufpV2TUvtBbqWmUIxgt+Xz5rqXEeyJRbbWXIGD2BIJ/UCpzi2Jc5JUxr47g68+kQjCl42UE8+lUvBVuE1O1lLZdsPnnIBB4/Sm3jH+2+myLHudFyhJxjnmqHhpgut2yJFsTIA5z2zTG/kJeRuFIy/iy1e51DVP7h6YvWBGfcn5VdsfD8YuLa6fZNaGDdnPBc5GMe3NWtft2kvbyFQFYXbuGH+WSe/6UaRdTWNuIHXcqOWQqe2e4xUWTZU5Jw12dksvs1iYkVHTJbJXBGTkAVBqOjrqNxbSTFVSJd4APO4KMZqe/ee/Gy3JiKncQTwR717utTjtYWkYAsqAbQwAOBjNXzTM0eVFK4iZdDtOrH0ZcIrA9147cUji0T7ffTs06LEjbgW53ADz961l000unwygIj9QFfaqFtvto5m6YaRyMENj50DnTNWOlGpE+i6TYyafNd9EZaaNNmeAvYkfX9660FghhtZYsyko24nvk8gj0xUFpJcWsdrEhbppKzS4PDLjgfng1bFyu1G6GbgFA7nzRWB/PiheT7JcbJG0+3t7j7OIcvskkO04yPIUV5Fyr7uurNjqhdp5CNzjNFEpoF5GLrK3BsoCc/hr2OPIVaWEKAAg4qGyDfYoO/4SfsKnCt/yJrPJNsN5JP2d6Yznpiu7PiBIxkiuEEf5H5ZoGcj5jzqJAW/ZpPFyrssOB+Ge9LtAAGs2zEAndTDxf93T8/8AWaXeHxnV7fHk1Nf9oWutnnVUU6reHAz1n/eoo4MqZHISMdzVvVIY01G6kmY/isVQdzzVCWQzMMnAHYDypclTKIdTvorO0Z9oCL91R3Y1noLV0ni1bU76W2jYgp0eX9segpRrmoS3N/OjNtjjYqiD9T86nTUheRWUDFN1uCGRxnI7AkVphGkHGkaq31i3uLuWyjn6qcNEW43DA8vWr2zHlj60hvNLhnjsrqJhBcQhG3Jj4lyMj/ynszW6sWiuN8RAKtuHas+Rb0VI4yqT2rgUD7orz1It34gOe2CK7leDvznyyKVsA66DptlQPhNFDLhWBJ7HvRVoJIX2Vvm0gG5vwk/yPoKsBSg2hjz70UUTewjghGdxOTXtVCnI9v3ooqJ7IzR+LRuXTxnnpn/VLGH2Eb4/xc8N6UUU2fYBU3NI7OzEsTkk9zQVFFFIIYDxVbfZdXl2HiYdQD0z3/apdAv/ALPA1s8auhY7coMgtwcn60UVvj0EjWai3SuDDGQ+5Qz70A7DHHoavC2Zgro6N2OXjAIX0wOPaiik5G10WyuYJTlQ0QAG5m2ct6cduAccV5FtIpP9xPulfwh7UUUjk32CTAFYcZyADyaKKKAJH//Z" alt="" id="vidthumb2" class="th vidthumb2" style="display:inline-block;height:70px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;border:0;width:120px" align="middle" border="0" height="70" width="120">
</div>
<span class="vdur" style="right:0;background-color:#000;bottom:0;color:#000;filter:alpha(opacity=70);font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;opacity:0.7;-khtml-opacity:0.7;-moz-opacity:0.7;padding:1px 3px;position:absolute;text-align:right;text-decoration:none">►&nbsp;4:40</span>
<span class="vdur" style="right:0;bottom:0;color:#fff;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;padding:1px 3px;position:absolute;text-align:right;text-decoration:none">►&nbsp;4:40</span>
</a>
</div>
</td>
<td style="padding-top:1px" valign="top">
<h3 class="r inl">
<a href="http://www.footytube.com/video/southampton-manchester-united-sep02-127801" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','0','','2','AFQjCNE5svFiL4Af9K2TuhaGf4ydP-LjtQ','t7BFtngpHDrP_gEBAAj7eg','0CD4QtwIwAQ',null,event)" title="Southampton vs. Manchester United Video Highlights &amp; Interviews (02nd Sep 12)">Southampton vs. <em>Manchester</em> United Video <b>...</b>
</a>
</h3>
<div> <cite class="kv">footytube.com</cite>
<span class="st">
<span class="f">
<span style="background:#aaa;border:#999 1px solid;border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;color:#fff;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;margin-right:5px;padding:0 3px;text-transform:uppercase">New</span>
<span class="nobr">13 hours ago</span> - <span class="nobr">5 min</span>
</span>
<br>Southampton v <em>Manchester</em> United video highlights, results and news. Match  played on Sunday, Sep 02 2012 <b>...</b>
<br>
</span>
</div> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--n-->
<!--m-->
</li>
<li class="g videobox" style="position:relative">
<div class="s">
<table class="ts" style="width:auto">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top:5px;padding-right:8px" valign="top" width="1%">
<div class="th" style="background-color:#000;height:68px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:120px">
<a id="v0" style="text-decoration:none" href="/url?url=http://www.footytube.com/video/southampton-manchester-united-sep02-127812&amp;rct=j&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=P2hEUIfkKYKk0QXppoHgCA&amp;ved=0CEIQuAIwAg&amp;q=manchester&amp;usg=AFQjCNEBZOpSGbL3i-xMze45YxunEAhAag">
<div style="position:relative;top:-1px;left:0px">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="" id="vidthumb3" class="th vidthumb3" style="display:inline-block;height:70px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;border:0;width:120px" align="middle" border="0" height="70" width="120">
</div>
<span class="vdur" style="right:0;background-color:#000;bottom:0;color:#000;filter:alpha(opacity=70);font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;opacity:0.7;-khtml-opacity:0.7;-moz-opacity:0.7;padding:1px 3px;position:absolute;text-align:right;text-decoration:none">►&nbsp;5:53</span>
<span class="vdur" style="right:0;bottom:0;color:#fff;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;padding:1px 3px;position:absolute;text-align:right;text-decoration:none">
```

with this code:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML
html = html.replace( /2012/g, "???" );
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML =html;
```

In this code i want to replace `2012` with `????`

But I want to replace every number in the  value by ??? but not replace the numbers in url.

Is that possible?

Comment: You have `<li>` as a direct child of `<td>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the URLs all use slash `-` in the URL you could do something like:

```
html = html.replace( /[^\-]2012/g, " ???" );
```

Comment: In what browser? All I have tried worked. See http://jsfiddle.net/WMvKh/ as reference.